# How do I run a task in the background with a delay?

Tags: python, time, sleep

I have the following code:

```
import time


def wait10seconds():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)

    return 'Counted to 10!'


print(wait10seconds())

print('test')
```

Now my question is how do you make `print('test')` run before the function `wait10seconds()` is executed without exchanging the 2 lines.

I want the output to be the following:

```
test
Counted to 10!
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Threads` for this

like:

```py
from threading import Thread
my_thread = Thread(target=wait10seconds) # Create a new thread that exec the function
my_thread.start() # start it
print('test') # print the test
my_thread.join() # wait for  the function to end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects). Taken from the Python docs page:

```
def hello():
    print("hello, world")

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start()  # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 3.5+ you can use asyncio:

```
import asyncio
async def wait10seconds():
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 'Counted to 10!'

print(asyncio.run(wait10seconds()))
```

`asyncio.run` is new to python 3.7, for python 3.5 and 3.6 you won't be able to use `asyncio.run` but you can achieve the same thing by working with the event_loop directly